# How to take shots like this

Tags: post-processing, long-exposure, gopro, high-speed

[image][image]

I want to know how to take shots like this on a motorcycle on a gopro hero 8. 
Is this effect done in post?

Comment: Ummm... 1) Buy/rent a GoPro, 2) either attach it to your helmet or a selfie stick, 3) go riding somehow without killing yourself....????

Comment: Effect ? What effect are talking about? Figure out what it is about the photos that you like and try to explain in detail why you like them and what you think is the best way to ask about how they are achieved.

Comment: Please read [Important information for asking "What's this effect?" questions](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/important-information-for-asking-whats-this-effect-questions) and edit this post accordingly. Make sure to use a descriptive title, too. Thank you!

Comment: I hope the second picture wasn't shot in the same conditions than the first one. That is: in 5th gear, over 90 km/h, with a curve ahead...

Comment: @MrUpsidDown Could be MPH (but landscape looks Italian/Spanih)

Comment: does anybody know what those two seemingly liquid filled containers are?

Comment: Step 1: Buy a motorcycle...

Comment: @ths They're reservoirs for brake (right) and clutch (left) fluid.

Answer (score 5):

No need for post processing.

Relative to the camera, the motorcycle and rider are not moving (unless the rider waves the selfie-stick) so they are sharp. The background (clouds and landscape) are changing very little due to the distance, so they also look sharp. The road and nearby shoulder to move quickly relative to the camera, so are subject to motion blur, and this effect is more pronounced near the camera than far from it.

So, you just need the adequate shutter speed. Since the bike is moving at 90km/h (25m/s) and the blur tracks are roughly 50cm, the pictures are likely shot around 1/60s-1/100s.

Comment: This answer sounds reasonable - and makes a case for getting rid of downvoting without leaving a comment.

Comment: This makes sense